# Scope value does not reflect in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

I really need your help... I have problem in updating scope in my ASP.Net MVC/AngularJS.

The issue with `$scope.svFullName` ... It does not reflect in the view when I change its value even though it is changing in the JS code because i have tested it from the js. Here is my code:

View:

```
<td ng-repeat="x in supervisors | limitTo:1" style="width: 60%;">
<div ng-show="!svElements">{{svFullName}}</div>
<div ng-show="svElements">
    <select ng-model='svFullName' ng-selected='svFullName'>
        <option ng-repeat="z in supervisorsList">{{z.supervisorfName + " " + z.supervisorlName}}</option>
    </select>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Save</a>                                                                                                
</div>
```

Edit
    Save

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/Home/GetSupervisor')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.supervisors = response.data;
        $scope.svFullName = response.data[0].supervisorfName + " " + response.data[0].supervisorlName;
        $scope.defaultsvFullName = $scope.svFullName;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });

$http.get('/Home/GetSupervisorsList')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.supervisorsList = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });

$scope.svElements = false;
$scope.toggleSV = function () {
    if ($scope.svElements) {
        $scope.svFullName = $scope.defaultsvFullName;
    }
    $scope.svElements = !$scope.svElements;
}
});
```

The `$scope.svFullName` is bonded with the `div`, so when I click on edit, and when I change the name, the `$scope.svFullName` will be changed... What I want to do is, changing back the `$scope.svFullName` to its default value when I click on cancel.

The value does not reflect in the view

Comment: can you please create plunker? provide supervisors and supervisorsList data.

Comment: Good idea, I will try to create one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UPDATED to online version with $http get... you can return object or string or id, see the example

```js
        var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.showList = true;
            $scope.defaultValue = {};

            var root = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

            $http.get(root + "/users").success(function (response) {
                $scope.supervisorsList = response;
                $scope.defaultValue = $scope.supervisorsList[0];
                $scope.svFullName = $scope.supervisorsList[0];
            });

            //default

            //reset
            $scope.reset = function () {
                $scope.showList = false;
                $scope.svFullName = $scope.defaultValue;
            }

        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>{{svFullName.name}}</div>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="svFullName" ng-show="showList" ng-options="z as z.name for z in supervisorsList"></select>
        <button ng-show="showList" ng-click="showList = false">save</button>
        <button ng-show="showList" ng-click="reset()">cancel</button>
        <button ng-hide="showList" ng-click="showList = true">change</button>
    </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Maher, my issue is not when I change the select item? In my code the scope reflected with the dropbox properly. But when I click on cancel to hide the list, I want to reset the `$scope.svFullName` to its default value. Please check my code one more time.

Comment: Hi @AhmedAlsahli, please check the answer again.

Comment: Thank you Maher, it is very very strange... Yes, it is working here but not in my code. If you see my code, I am using `$http.get` and assigning the default values done in `.then`... Do you think this has something to do?

Comment: @AhmedAlsahli, you can't get "defaultsvFullName" because this is in the get method, set "defaultsvFullName" before get as null, and then after you get first value you can define it as "defaultsvFullName"

Comment: Understood, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Please check working example : [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JbU5MqoWvavXRH2aFEij?p=preview)

Change your variable to object i.e

```
$scope.svFullName to $scope.name.svFullName
```

Because ng-repeat creates its own scope, for more information please check -

**[Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)**

In app.js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('supervisor.json')
        .then(function (response) {
              $scope.supervisors = response.data;
              $scope.name = {};
              $scope.name.svFullName = response.data[0].supervisorfName + " " + response.data[0].supervisorlName;
              $scope.defaultsvFullName = $scope.name.svFullName;

         })
         .catch(function (e) {
              console.log("error", e);
              throw e;
          })
          .finally(function () {
               console.log("This finally block");
          });

   $http.get('supervisor-list.json')
        .then(function (response) {
              $scope.supervisorsList = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
              console.log("error", e);
              throw e;
        })
        .finally(function () {
              console.log("This finally block");
        });

        $scope.svElements = false;
        $scope.toggleSV = function () {

             if ($scope.svElements) {
                  $scope.name.svFullName = $scope.defaultsvFullName;

             }
             $scope.svElements = !$scope.svElements;
       }
 })
```

In HTML

```
<div ng-click="svElements = !svElements"> Edit</div>
   <div ng-repeat="x in supervisors | limitTo:1" style="width: 60%;">
       <div ng-show="!svElements">{{name.svFullName}}</div>
       <div ng-show="svElements">
            <select ng-model='name.svFullName' ng-selected='name.svFullName'>
                  <option ng-repeat="z in supervisorsList">{{z.supervisorfName + " " + z.supervisorlName}}</option>
            </select>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Save</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="toggleSV()">cancel</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, I cannot express how much I am happy with this answer. Thank you very much, you provided it in a very easy way.

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating code to following

```
 $scope.defaultsvFullName = response.data[0].supervisorfName + " " + response.data[0].supervisorlName;
```

in below method

```
$http.get('/Home/GetSupervisor')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.supervisors = response.data;
        $scope.svFullName = response.data[0].supervisorfName + " " + response.data[0].supervisorlName;
        $scope.defaultsvFullName = response.data[0].supervisorfName + " " + response.data[0].supervisorlName;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Nothing changed. I don't see any differences between this and the original code though?

Comment: I would confirm that as I said, the `$scope.svFullName` value is actually changed, but it does not reflect in the view. In other word, if I do `alert($scope.svFullName)` in the last part after changing back the scope it will display the right value, but the view don't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try $scope.$digest after value change

Answer (score 0):

You are using a value tag in ng-repeat select

```
 <option value="{{z.supervisorfName + " " + z.supervisorlName}}" ng-repeat="z in supervisorsList">{{z.supervisorfName + " " + z.supervisorlName}}</option>
```

> > You can also use ng-options 
> >     https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: What differences could do?

Comment: if you wont add value to option then angular wont be able to match your model with the list of options

Comment: i added this value="{{z.supervisorfName + " " + z.supervisorlName}}"

Comment: I see, let me try it out and I will let you know

Comment: But I think ng-model is taking care of the value. Besides, what is the relation between this and the scope value?